# IBM APIM ADP Search does not support wild card

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management

When searching in the IBM API Management Advanced Developer Portal it does not support wild card searches.  Is there any alternative method to do the search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in search from Drupal does not support wildcard search.

The current search functionality will auto suggest as you type - however - only exact match searches are conducted.

To workaround this issue you may make use of Apache Solr module. This is a drop in replacement for the out of the box search. You need to stand up the Solr instance manually at this time.